# how to set datetime in pst

Tags: apex

I'm trying to update my datetime in the salesforce database to execute my process on specific date/time, at the end result, I want to see the datetime to be now() at 08:00 pm PST

here is what I have used:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime endTime = DateTime.newInstance(
  now.year(),  
  now.month(), 
  now.day(), 
  20, // 24 hour clock, from 0-23. 20= 8pm PST.
  0, // Minutes
  0); // Seconds
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
DateTime endTimeInPST = endTime.addSeconds(-tz.getOffset(endTime)/1000);
DateTime startTimeInPST = endTimeInPST.addDays(-1);
system.debug(startTimeInPST );

22:25:37:006 USER_DEBUG [13]|DEBUG|2021-06-08 10:00:00 //<<<it should be 8 pm PST
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the part from my previous answer where I stated you need to work in GMT. If you do not work in GMT, `DateTime.newInstance` returns a `DateTime` *in your user's time zone*, so it will be biased on your own user's time zone setting. When you then do the math, you'll be off by your user's time zone offset, especially since `DateTime.now()` is in GMT.

In my previous answer, we construct the time as (e.g. 8PM) in GMT, and *then* we subtract the local time zone offset by that amount, which makes the new resultant GMT equal to what would be 5PM in the desired timezone, PST.

Use the non-GMT versions if you want to work with your user's time zone. If you're *really* having a hard time with it, you could set your user's time zone to PST and use DateTime.newInstance. However, anyone that uses your code would also need to be in PST, or suffer the same fate as you're experiencing right now.

To get everything to line up, you must be willing to work in GMT, and **only** in GMT.